# How can the integral a divergent function such as $\ln(x)/\sqrt{x}$ be approximated within limits 0 to 1 where the function is not just even defined?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

What is the reason that some of the functions' integral with $\ln()$ can be approximated within limits where the function is not defined? For e.g. integral of $\ln(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ is $-1$ (however the function is not defined at $x=0$) neither the limit of function as $x$ tends to $0$ exists. So is the case for $\ln(x)$ divided by square root of $x$.

Comment: It is because the singularity at $x=0$ is integrable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral